# Ubuntu Guest on Windows 10 host, How to get maximum performance from Guest?

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization

I am in situations where I have Windows 10 as the main OS and I can't remove it or dual boot it. I had an Ubuntu 18.04 running in a virtualbox and I am using that for almost everything. Since its a vm, its a bit slow than the host. I looked around on the internet for a solution but most of it involves tinkering.

So my question here is "Is there some feature in VirtualBox which determines the amount of resources that will give the guest maximum performance possible?

P.S: I am a newbies so let me know if there is something wrong with question and how can I improve it.

Answer (score 0):

In the VB control panel you can set the maximum memory and number of processors that the VM will use.

Not sure you can do much better than this, since Windows is your host, you have to live will all its overhead and no-so-good I/O performance (are your Linux processes frequently in "disk sleep" mode?).

Comment: There's also guest additions that I.bet aren't installed. But of course, the OP should install Ubuntu or a dual boot if they're *using that for almost everything*.

Comment: Some of us are sentenced to Windows machines due to corporate regulations.

Comment: If you can boot from external devices, Ubuntu running from a USB 3.0 stick should work much better than a VM.

Comment: I started working on a project and the previous people were using windows so most of the scripts, guides and related stuff are for Windows. I will get rid of it once I have them migrated.
I was looking for an option that detects the free resources on windows host and allocated them to the guest machine. But I guess I will have to do them manually.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I am an old user of VirtualBox. Hadn't used it much on windows host though. I have installed guest additions. So clipsboards, file sharing, network bridge, access to usb devices etc. are working fine.